# Как сравнить значения в двух массивах и собрать уникальный массив?

Tags: php

задача такая,есть два массива со старыми и новыми свойствами,нужно элемент из одного массива сравнить с каждым элементом второго, сравнить совпадения,если совпадений нет, то кинуть в отельный массив

```
while($item = $h->fetch()) {

foreach ($data as $i) {
    if ($item['XML_ID'] == $i['id']) {
        $doubleArr[] = $item;

    } elseif ($item['NAME'] == $i['name']) {
        $replaceArr[] = $item;

    } else{
        $item += ['new_id' => $i['id']];
        $passArr[] = $item;

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: приведите пример входных массивов в виде php кода и ожидаемый результат

Comment: входные массивы с подмассивами,результат тоже массивы с подмассивами,то есть например в последний массив должны попадать элементы у которых нету совпадений,прошёл весь массив,сравнил,если ничего не нашёл кидаю в последний,последний массив вообще может быть копией первого

Comment: отлично. и чо в вашем коде не так?

Comment: последний массив получается большой с кучей повторяющихся элементов,что в принципе логично,но как сделать уникальный не пойму,то есть первым циклом while я прохожу по первому массиву,вторым циклом по второму

Comment: ну так проверяйте, что  в массиве уже есть такой?